# Oracle SQL HR sample schema: How do I make ALL of it usable for other users?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

So I was able to install Oracle Database, unlock the HR sample account and all that. What I want to do is make it so other users (ones I create) can use the HR data tables, triggers, indexes, the whole nine yards for themselves. This was how an SQL class I just took at school was set up for us. Now I want to do the same thing at home for me and possibly a friend to practice with

I know how to export/import the tables for other users, but I feel like I need to do more than that. Essentially, how can I duplicate everything the HR user has to others?

Thank you! :)

Comment: do you want copies of the objects made for other schemas, or do you want other DB users to be able to access the objects? GRANT X on HR.Y to PUBLIC will give everyone in the db the ability to do X on Y

Answer (score 1):

If this is just for play - the easiest thing is to grant DBA privilege to every new user you create.